# Is there a rails gem to use a single table for all of the "options" in multiple select inputs throughout an app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, input, rubygems, sti

So, sometimes you just need a list of options for your selects. Is there a simple gem out there that makes it easy to use one table for all the types of options you might have in your app?

This table would likely look like:

```
id  | type   | value  | label
01  | color  | red    | Red
02  | color  | black  | Black
03  | shape  | circle | Circle
04  | shape  | square | Square
05  | state  | texas  | Texas
```

For instance, a list of countries, a list of states, a list of colors, a list of months, etc...

Then when using a select:

```
select_tag :color, options_for_colors
```

Then it would populate the select with options with values/labels from some options table, where the rows have a type of :color.

This would be easy enough to roll on my own but I don't want to spend the time if its already built.

**update**

I'd like this to be a dynamic table, so the end user can add/remove items from the select options table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this method,

app/models/user.rb

```
ROLES = %w[admin author normal]
```

app/views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :titleize %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty succinct, but I was looking for something more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 3.2, here's what I do in the initializer:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.types
    Rails.application.routes.routes.select do |r|
      r.defaults[:action]=="index" && r.defaults[:controller]== self.name.to_s.downcase.pluralize
    end.map do |r|
      r.defaults[:type]
    end.compact
  end
end
```

And in routes.rb I map STI actions to parent model's controller because I'm controller savvy:

```
  resources :derived_models, :controller => :base_model, :type => "DerivedModel"
  resources :more_derived_models, :controller => :base_model, :type => "MoreDerivedModel"
```

Now, `Model.types` will give you `["DerivedModel", "MoreDerivedModel"]`

Comment: This looks like it just gives you back a list of STI subclasses? Not sure how it answers the original question :( Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, it is a "single table" solution for listing options Or maybe I misunderstood your intention.